# Is my iPhone hacked based on SysSecInfo anomalies?

Tags: iphone, ios, security

I installed an app SysSecInfo and it shows 'anomalies' and 'custom jailbreak'. It doesn't explain what is anomalis about it or what it means. How do I know if my iPhone is hacked or if the app is broken?

[image]
[image]
[image]

iPhone 5, iOS 10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app hasn't been updated for iOS 10.2. It expects a previous system, so changes that have occurred as part of Apple's iOS updates are detected as anomalies. Everything looks normal in your screenshots. Furthermore, the AccessibilityBundles was always a known bug as that was shown even when they *were* expected.